# How to get XML attributes with PHP

Tags: php, xml

This is my xml file:

```
<device name=" name ">
<interface>
    <ip > someip </ip>
</interface>
<display>
    <name> \\.\DISPLAY1 ( 1920 X 1080 )</name>
</display>
<output>
    <audio> Speakers (High Definition Audio </audio>
    <audio> Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De </audio>
    <audio> Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De </audio>
</output>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<body style="font-family: Arial">
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("device.xml");
    var_dump($xml);
    $attr = $xml->device->attributes()->name;
?>
<div id="leftDiv">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><?php echo $attr; ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainDiv">

</div>
<div id="rightDiv">

</div>
```

I want to reach device's name attribute and get its value, but I always get an error: main(): Node no longer exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php on line 30. Line 30 is this line: $attr = $xml->device->attributes()->name; What's wrong?

Comment: The XML you've posted is not valid (it has no root element). Could you construct a [mcve] which you can actually test and gives the same error? If the error is indeed on the line `$attr = $xml->device->attributes()->name;` we should only need to see those three lines of PHP.

Comment: <device> is a root element itself, simply there is the closing tag missing in this snippet.

Comment: OK, that's an easy mistake to make. There's still more PHP code than we need here, though; just the two lines beginning `$xml=...` and `$attr=...` would have been your [mcve],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**php file code**

remove `device` from `$xml->device->attributes()->name;`

```
<body style="font-family: Arial">
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("device.xml");
    var_dump($xml);
    $attr = $xml->attributes()->name;
?>
<div id="leftDiv">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><?php echo $attr; ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainDiv">

</div>
<div id="rightDiv">

</div>
```

**xml file**

missing `</device>` to end of file so put it

```
<device name=" name ">
<interface>
    <ip > someip </ip>
</interface>
<display>
    <name> \\.\DISPLAY1 ( 1920 X 1080 )</name>
</display>
<output>
    <audio> Speakers (High Definition Audio </audio>
    <audio> Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De </audio>
    <audio> Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De </audio>
</output>
</device>
```

Comment: Tip:`$xml->attributes()->name` can be written more concisely as `$xml['name'];`